# Converting XML to Json for NiFi Split Processor with Attribute fields

Tags: json, xml, schema, apache-nifi

In NiFi, I'm trying to utilise the SplitRecord processor to change incoming XML files to Json.

The structure of the XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
   <doc boost="1.0">
      <field name="id">12345</field>
      <field name="name">john smith</field>
      <field name="age">34</field>
   </doc>
   <doc boost="1.0">
      <field name="id">74832</field>
      <field name="name">jane doe</field>
      <field name="age">16</field>
   </doc>
   <doc boost="1.0">
      <field name="id">08423</field>
      <field name="name">henry jones</field>
      <field name="age">29</field>
   </doc>
</docs>
```

I want to split each record but I also was to have the attributes of the field represented instead of just field itself being one giant array with no identifier.

Right now, in the SplitRecord processor I'm using XMLreader controller and JSONsetrecordWriter controller. If I just let the XML reader infer the schema, I get the following result

```
{ "doc": [ {
    "field" : ["12345", "john smith", "34"]
    },
    {
    "field" : ["74832", "jane doe", "16"]
    },
    {
    "field" : ["08423", "henry jones", "29"]
    } ]
}
```

You can see all the fields have lost their metadata, I want something closer to this:

```
{ 
"id":"12345",
"name":"john smith",
"age":"34"
},
{ 
"id":"74832",
"name":"jane doe",
"age":"16"
},
{ 
"id":"08423",
"name":"henry jones",
"age":"29"
}
```

In the XMLReader controller, if I switch to use "Schema Text" property, and in the schema text property field I put in this schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "docs",
  "namespace" : "doc",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "boost", "type" : "string"
  }, 
  {
    "name" : "field",
    "type" : {
        "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "record",
              "name" : "field",
              "namespace" : "name",
              "fields" : [ 
              {"name" : "id","type": "string"},
              {"name":"name","type":"string"},
              {"name":"age","type":"string"}
              ]
            }
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

I get no result, in fact the output is now this:

```
{"boost":null,"field":[]}
```

I would really appreciate any help in where my schema is wrong in trying to convert this XML to JSON.

## Update

I've determined my working schema

```
{
  "name": "docs",
  "namespace": "doc",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
      {
         "name" : "field",
         "type" : {
         "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "record",
              "name" : "field",
              "namespace" : "name",
              "fields" : [ 
                          {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
                          {"name": "value", "type": "string"}
                         ]
                      }
                  }
       }
     ]
}
```

in the xmlreader controller, also set the following properties:

**Schema Access Strategy**: "Use 'Schema Text' Property"

**Schema Text**: *the above schema*

**Expect Records as Array**: true

**Field Name for Content**: value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is to create a second schema that matches your desired output. Then use [JoltTransformRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-jolt-record-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.jolt.record.JoltTransformRecord/index.html) to run a Jolt transformation. You would want to do a two-step for that like this:

`Convert/SplitRecord` -> `JoltTransformRecord`

Also, for your use case described, use `ConvertRecord` instead of `SplitRecord` unless you have A LOT of records and just want to split things up. If you're splitting records down to 1 record a piece, that's a very inefficient flow. The Record API can handle anywhere from 1 record at a time to several million records easily.

Comment: thanks @Mike Thomsen, I will take on your note to use ConvertRecord instead. So I'm gathering from what you're saying that its not possible to go straight from XML to JSON in the format I'm wanted with the use of a schema, I will need the JoltTransformRecord as well?

Comment: I've been able to determine the schema, I will post it as an update to the original post for anyone it may help. I'll also accept your answer because it did help me in what my flow should look like

Comment: Correct on the need for a second step. Convert/SplitRecord cannot transform the record to that extent in a single step because they are not designed to do that.